# Heap Corruption Detected with Only CMake

Tags: c, visual-c++, cmake

I am trying to follow along with buildyourownlisp tutorials but I am having a problem freeing memory that I am storing user inputs.
I thought I made a mistake in the lisp implementation part but even if I delete everything except reading input and trying to freeing the memory I am getting the `Heap Corruption Detected` error as the image below:

[image]

```
    char* readline(char* prompt){
        fputs(prompt, stdout);
        fgets(input_buffer, 2048, stdin);

        char* copy = malloc(strlen(input_buffer+1));
        strcpy(copy, input_buffer);
        copy[strlen(copy)-1] = '\0';

        return copy;
    }
```

```
    while (1){
        char* input = readline("hello> ");
        free(input);
    }
```

I realized that I am getting this error if I use CMake.

Tried using GCC directly and it works without a problem.

Thank you.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(input_buffer+1))` Typo?

Comment: @dxiv omg. I spend hours trying to thank you. feel a little embarrassed. but why this is only a problem when I use cname.
can it because cmake build a debug version? that actually makes sense I guess.

Comment: Could well be, debug builds are better at that. You had a 2-byte buffer overflow, which is not much and could have otherwise passed unnoticed for a while.

Comment: Use the answer button instead of editing the solution into your question

Comment: @ArdentCoder I didn't. Hitokiri fixed my formatting, thanks for that. Also fixing type also fixed the issue and another problem too. 

Some times even though inputs are the same, I was getting errors. Fixing this overflow also fixed that.